# Why does FFMPEG incorrectly guess .M4A to be a WAV pcm_s16le file?

Tags: ffmpeg, wav, codec, aac, m4a

I'm trying to extract a section of audio with this command;

```
  ffmpeg -ss 00:00:01 -i input.m4a -t 00:00:03 -c:a copy output.m4a
```

But FFMPEG incorrectly guesses the .M4A to be a WAV pcm_s16le file so I have to use this command and convert to AAC for the .M4A output;

```
  ffmpeg -vn -ss 00:00:01 -i input.m4a -t 00:00:03 -c:a aac output.m4
```

But I'm worried that this may lead to it being processed twice. So how do I get FFMPEG to recognise that the output file should remain in the same format as the input file and simply be copied instead of converted?

Answer (score 1):

> -ss from second 01
> -t  take 3 seconds
> -vn dont copy video

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:01 -i input.m4a -t 3 -c:a aac -vn -strict -2 output.m4a
```

> just copy audio

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:01 -i input.m4a -t 3 -c:a copy -vn -strict -2 output.m4a
```

Comment: The 1st one gave me a smaller compressedfile. The 2nd gave me an error; [ipod @ 00000273cdf0f680] Could not find tag for codec pcm_s16le in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --

Comment: So I'm unable to simply copy the audio without compressing it.

Comment: `-strict -2` \ `-strict experimental` hasn't been needed for AAC encoding since 2015.